# Need to get output of 2 tables in one column using joins only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this scenario question which needs to be solved using joins only. can't use except,intersect or union.

sample code:

```
--demo setup
create table t1 (id int)
insert into t1 values (1),(2),(3)

create table t2 (id int)
insert into t2 values (4),(5),(6)

--join
select t1.id,t2.id
from t1 full outer join
t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

--after join i am getting

```
id          id
----------- -----------
1           NULL
2           NULL
3           NULL
NULL        4
NULL        5
NULL        6
```

--But i need is

```
id          
----------- 
1           
2           
3           
4        
5        
6
```

Can someone help me with this ? i know this can be easily done using union but this challenge needs to be solved using joins only.

any help is appreciated ....

Answer (score 0):

--solved the challenge after adding case to the code.

```
select case when t1.id is null then t2.id else t1.id end as id
from t1 full outer join
t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: If a common number available in both table, final list is showing the number for once in your script output.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
 SELECT case when t1.id IS NULL THEN t2.id ELSE t1.id END AS id
 FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2
 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

As you said the Use From Union

```
select * from t1
union 
select * from t2
```

Comment: I have mentioned that union can't be used.
and your code does not work left join can only bring columns from left table.

Answer (score 0):

Although UNION ALL is the better option, you can use this following script-

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN C.ID1 IS NULL THEN C.ID2 ELSE C.ID1 END V
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT 'T1' TabName1,id ID1 FROM @t1 
    )A
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT 'T2' TabName2,id ID2 FROM @t2
    )B
    ON A.TabName1 = B.TabName2
)C
ORDER BY 1
```